# #Value! error when writing formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a piece of code that loops down a column and inserts a formula into each cell in that column.  The code runs, the only problems is that each cell the formula is inserted into displays #Value!  Does anyone know how to fix this?
Here is the piece of code with the problem:

```
Dim j As Long

'Loop down the rows in mainfile

For j = 2 To lastFullRow2


 ' Make each argument a string, then concatenate it all all into large string

    Dim firstArgument As String
    firstArgument = "ws_multidax.Range(" & valuecolumnLetter & "2:" & valuecolumnLetter & lastFullRow1 & ")"

    Dim secondArgument As String
    secondArgument = "ws_multidax.Range(" & parameter1columnLetter & "2:" & parameter1columnLetter & lastFullRow1 & ")"


    Dim thirdArgument As String
    thirdArgument = "ws_multidax.Range(" & parameter2columnLetter & "2:" & parameter2columnLetter & lastFullRow1 & ")"

    Dim fourthArgument As String
    fourthArgument = "ws_multidax.Range(" & parameter2columnLetter & "2:" & parameter2columnLetter & lastFullRow1 & ")"

    Dim condition3 As String
    condition3 = "ws_mainfile.Range(" & "D2:" & D & j & ")"


    Dim patid1 As String
    patid1 = "ws_multidax.Range(" & "D2:" & D & lastFullRow2 & ")"

        With ws_mainfile

Dim commandstring As String

'The formula we want is a concatenated string

commandstring = "{=INDEX(" & firstArgument & ",MATCH(1,(" & secondArgument & "=" & condition1 & ")*(" & thirdArgument & "=" & condition2 & ")*(" & patid1 & "=" & condition3 & "),0))}"

'Insert the formula into each cell as the loop goes down the rows

ws_mainfile.Range("AN" & j).Formula = Eval(commandstring)
'ws_mainfile.Range("AN" & j).Formula = commandstring

        End With           

Next j
```

The #Value! gets put into the cells when I run the line with the Eval(commandstring).  When I run the line with just formula = commandstring, the formula gets put in each cell, but it does not solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 2 problems:

1. You are putting in the curly braces of an array formula manually, don't do this
2. You are putting in an array formula as a regular formula

So to correct, do the following:

```
'1. Change this line:
commandstring = "{=INDEX(....)}"

'And simply remove the curly braces {} from its beginning and end
commandstring = "=INDEX(....)"


'2. Change this line:
ws_mainfile.Range("AN" & j).Formula = Eval(commandstring)

'To use the .FormulaArray property instead of just .Formula:
ws_mainfile.Range("AN" & j).FormulaArray = commandstring
```

Comment: When I do that, I get Application-defined or object-defined error at the line:                     .FormulaArray = commandstring

Comment: That's because of how you've defined your arguments. You've defined them like VBA ranges intead of like worksheet ranges, which are of the style `SheetName!A1:A10` for example, or if your sheetnames have spaces, it would be `'Sheet Name`!A1:A10` and of course if you want an absolute reference (won't change as formula is copied to other rows or columns), you'll need to use the $ symbol to make that happen: `'Sheet Name!$A$1:$A$10`.  Once you've corrected all of your arguments to contain valid formula range references instead of VBA range references, you'll no longer get that error.

Comment: Cool, thanks!  But when the ranges are defined with strings like mine are, how would add the sheet name in?  Do I just do 'Range(" Sheet1! & valuecolumnLetter..)?

Comment: No need for the Range() method at all.  Just put it in like you would put it in on a worksheet, but building a string: `"Sheet1!" & valuecolumnLetter & ...`

Comment: Ok got it, but just one more thing, how would I reference other workbooks now? ws_mainfile and ws_multidax are different workbooks.

Comment: in that case, you may want a different approach.  Hard to give better advice without knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the snag, basically I'm comparing data in two different workbooks based on criteria in the third.  I think what I'll do is move the data in the sheets I need from the other workbooks, and put it in the other sheets of the workbook I'm writing the code in.  That way everything will be in the same workbook.  Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.  There's no need to use the eval function, as you have built a string formula in code.  The problem is you have surrounded it with the braces, which excel treats as if you had entered text.

Try this instead:

```
commandstring = "=INDEX(" & firstArgument & ",MATCH(1,(" & secondArgument & "=" & condition1 & ")*(" & thirdArgument & "=" & condition2 & ")*(" & patid1 & "=" & condition3 & "),0))"

'Insert the formula into each cell as the loop goes down the rows

ws_mainfile.Range("AN" & j).Formula = commandstring
```